# Sending messages from completion blocks causes EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, uialertcontroller

To address backwards compatibility for `UIAlertView` I have come up with an interface that would seem to work for iOS versions 8 and lower.

In addition to that, I have few classes that are responsible for managing an idle timer once the app has been launched. Upon completion of ~30 minutes of idle time an alert is shown to the user.

Based on user actions, appropriate methods defined in the app delegate are called.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e4082bb0291c59660ee2) is a link to the gist

and [link](https://github.com/amieka/SessionTimer) to the github project itself

Inside SPTimer.m you would notice "- (void) showIdleAlert " is triggering the crash.

I have set NSZombieEnabled to YES. Yet no proper call trace.

On running 'bt' inside the debugger the following errors are seen.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2c301d, 0x0000000101884017 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18080100)
    frame #0: 0x0000000101884017 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23
  * frame #1: 0x000000010133459c SessionTimer`__32-[UIAlertMode initAlertWith::::]_block_invoke10(.block_descriptor=0x00007f8fe2765280, action=0x00007f8fe2769c90) + 76 at UIAlertMode.m:55
    frame #2: 0x0000000102216097 UIKit`-[UIAlertController _fireOffActionOnTargetIfValidForAction:] + 55
    frame #3: 0x00000001022165d9 UIKit`__85-[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:triggeredByPopoverDimmingView:]_block_invoke + 30
    frame #4: 0x00000001020c179c UIKit`-[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 1118
    frame #5: 0x00000001020c3b17 UIKit`__56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 133
    frame #6: 0x0000000102711ac3 UIKit`-[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 110
    frame #7: 0x00000001020319f3 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 326
    frame #8: 0x0000000102019d9a UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 209
    frame #9: 0x000000010201a0d0 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 76
    frame #10: 0x00000001058a499e QuartzCore`CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 308
    frame #11: 0x00000001041177f4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #12: 0x0000000104100991 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 956
    frame #13: 0x0000000101b3c569 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    frame #14: 0x0000000101aff46b CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2043
    frame #15: 0x0000000101afea06 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    frame #16: 0x000000010519c9f0 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #17: 0x0000000101fc0550 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
    frame #18: 0x0000000101333e63 SessionTimer`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5e8cf2c8) + 115 at main.m:14
    frame #19: 0x000000010414c145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

I admit that my design is not good and I might be doing something fundamentally wrong here. Would appreciate feedback.

Comment: Answering my own question. Apparently I was referencing my block as an assign property and not copy hence the crash. Here is a reference to the original post that was answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812692/exc-bad-access-on-customised-blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I was referencing my block as an `assign` property and not `copy` hence the crash. Here is a reference to the original post that was answered [EXC_BAD_ACCESS on customised blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812692/exc-bad-access-on-).

Thanks